# Why squid not processing HTTPS request from Linux machines and windows clients can access https

Tags: proxy, squid, ubuntu-10.04

I am having squid proxy running on port 3128 with 2 nic

```
eth0:192.168.2.22 with internet access.

eth1:192.168.1.1 connected to LAN.
```

Every machines in LAN have ip in the range

```
192.168.1.0/24 through DHCP.
```

It includes both windows and Linux machines(**Ubuntu 10.04**).

All the windows machines can access **HTTPS** pages but none of the linux machine can access https page.

When a request is made for https from linux machines,its returning webpage not available.In the squid access log no "**CONNECT**" request is made when accessed from Linux machine.

What can be the reason?

**Squid running**: on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

**squid version**:squid3-3.1.19

No access restriction is made in the default squid configuration other than enabling localnet to connect.

tried setting

```
  export HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.1:3128/ in bashrc
```

but still not able to acces any https pages.

**env https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:3128/ wget --debug https://google.com/**

```
 DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

 --2012-10-26 13:45:47--  https://google.com/
  Connecting to 192.168.1.1:3128... connected.
  Created socket 3.
  Releasing 0x08e0a430 (new refcount 0).
  Deleting unused 0x08e0a430.

  ---request begin---
  CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.0
  User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)

  ---request end---
  proxy responded with: [HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established

  ]
 Initiating SSL handshake.
 Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x08e0a678
 certificate:
  subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
  issuer:  /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
ERROR: certificate common name `*.google.com' doesn't match requested host name     `google.com'.
 To connect to google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
 Closed 3/SSL 0x08e0a678
```

Comment: Is this a transparent proxy or not? I am guessing not but you've got the transparent-proxy tag. Demonstrate how you are testing the connectivity. Try running `env https_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:3128/ wget --debug https://google.com/` on the Linux machines, and see if that gives you a hint.

Comment: @chutz this is not a transparent proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to configure the HTTPS proxy in the Linux machines?

Comment: I didnt specify anything in linux machine.but specified proxy and its port in browser.

Comment: Make sure you specified a proxy for the HTTPS protocol, too.

Comment: yep...setting that variable fixed the issue,,,thanx

Comment: can u tell me why i cant ping public ip even with environment varibale set in .bashrc through terminal?

Comment: An HTTP proxy does not let you "ping" servers. Sorry, that's how it works. You can read up on the protocol, but it is out of scope here. I don't think I can **easily** explain.

Comment: i dont want to ping any...but i need to make ssh access to public servers,from the LAN.tried setting env in .bashrc but not much use.

Comment: Try this question to ssh over an http proxy. http://serverfault.com/questions/122862/connect-to-ssh-server-thru-80-via-http-proxy